# Какой смысл в правах на выполнение файла?

Tags: linux

Казалось бы, если есть доступ на чтение, то можно скопировать файл и исполнить его независимо от прав на выполнение. И наоборот, если прав на чтение нет, то выполнение должно быть невозможным вне зависимости от прав на выполнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несколько непонятен вопрос. Зачем бит "исполняемый"(x) в системе прав "я-мы-они(u-g-o)"? Затем, чтобы указать, что файл можно выполнять (независимо от расширений .exe и др.) Или зачем ограничивать права на исполнение кому-то, если есть права на чтение? А если нет? Кроме этого есть биты setuid и setgid, позволяющие выполнять задачи под uid и gid владельца.

Comment: Вопрос в излишности этого бита; в том, что биты "r" и "x" взаимозаменяют друг друга. И ваш пример с setuid здесь, кажется, единственно верный. Спасибо.

Comment: С SUID все не так просто. Во-первых, чтобы его дать файлу, нужно иметь права изменять этот файл. Во-вторых, некоторые важные программы определяют, выставлен ли SUID (т.е. отличаются ли EUID и RUID процесса) и отказываются работать, если обнаружат это.

К тому же, если нет бита Х, то никакие SUID не помогут запустить файл.

Comment: Извините, а откуда про взаимозаменяемость `x` и `r`? Кто запретит иметь права `-rwx--x--x`? или `---x--x--x`?

Comment: Мне кажется, автору вопроса не мешает еще немного почитать по основам никсов.

Answer (score 4):

Смысл в безопасности. Даже если скопировать файл, то без права на выполнение его не выполнить. И даже с правом на чтение и запись его не выполнить. Так устроено ядро линукса.

Comment: если это файл скрипта, то проблем нет, например, питоновские легко запускаются `python имя.py`. И права на запуск не нужны.

Comment: Это другое дело. Скрипт сам по себе не является исполняемым файлом.   Скриптовую программу выполняет интерпретатор.    Но если у Вас нет прав на запуск файла python, то Вы ничего не запустите. Можно запускать скрипты непосредственно, как экзешники, но для этого им тоже нужно иметь права для иполнения этого файла.

Comment: Вот почему вирусов под Linux гораздо меньше чем для Win-ды !

Comment: В том числе. ))) В юниксах главная задача вредоносной программы - получение прав рута, чтобы можно было делать, что захочет. Не получит прав - ничего не получит.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что под «безопасностью» вы подразумеваете некую защиту в стиле «не навреди себе сам»? А то ведь поменять права на своем файле нам никто не запрещает.
cp old new;
chmod u+x new;
./new;

Comment: Нет, не только. Если Вы не являетесь владельцем файла, то поменять его аттрибуты можно только из-под рута. А его еще получить нужно.

Comment: Ну я ведь всяко буду владельцем файла, получившегося при копировании.

Comment: ну так можно не дать скопировать (отобрав права на чтение).
А так, в целом, если глянуть грубо, то право не исполнение говорит, что этот файл нужно исполнять (да, тавтология). а исполняется в линуксе файл очень просто - считываются первые 2-3 символа файла и смотрится на них. Если там #! - значит до конца строки указан путь к программе, которая будет исполнять.
Если там "7f 45 4c 46" (.ELF) - значит это elf - типичный бинарник. И так дальше.
Именно по этой причине, можно создать файл с расширением gif, где будет путь к своему бинарнику, а исполнять будет исполнять свой скрипт.

Comment: Немного поразмыслив, я понял, что вопрос действительно интересный. Один из вариантов пользы: если в системе несколько параллельно работающий пользователей, то можно разрешить кому-то запускать файлы из моей директории (например, членам моей группы), а другим нет, плюс еще ограничить чтение и запись. Можно это сделать как для отдельных файлов, так и для директорий. В общем, это дает дополнительную гибкость системе безопасности и управления доступа.